# Swap partition on 13.04 not working

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, usb, swap

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Studio 1555 laptop and the swap partition isn't mounting or the system is just not using it. I have been using Ubuntu sense 10.04 and have never had this problem before, until 13.04. I have reinstalled it a few times and still it doesn't work and I have even install 13.04 on a USB drive and have it partitioned with both a ext4 and a swap partition in it was well and even on that USB drive it still doesn't use swap. Here is the output of the command 'free':

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4007744    1897780    2109964          0     122124     929832
-/+ buffers/cache:     845824    3161920
Swap:      4198396          0    4198396
```

In Gparted it shows that I have the swap partition with not errors on both the hard drive of my computer and the USB drive. So this is making me think it is something to do with Ubuntu but I can't seem to find where anyone else is having this issue. If there is anymore information you need just let me know what and where to get it and I will do what I can. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How much RAM does you system have?

Comment: 3.8 gb of RAM and my swappiness is at 60.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out what was going on. When I did `swapon -a` i would get this output:

```
swapon: cannot find the device for UUID=71911c52-b030-4ef0-a4f4-54785d79919b
```

so then I started thinking about it and checked the UUID of my swap partition and they were different so I checked the `etc/fstab` file and it had that my swap partition was the UUID above but I guess I changed the UUID at some point somehow... Anyways, I put the NEW UUID in the `etc/fstab` and now it it working fine... Not sure how this happened but apparently it was the user that was the problem and not the system, which is usually the issue. Thank you to Mitch for helping out. Hope this helps out anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some thing there.  I have turned swap off, and then back on, and I get the same output from `free`.  Which leads me to believe that the swap is there, but the system has no need to use it at the time you issued the command.

[image]

Comment: That would make sense, I did 'free' again out of curiosity when I first turned on my computer this time and I got all zeros across the line (under total, used, and free) and then went to gparted and right clicked on the swap partition and clicked information. Under 'status' it says "not active"... does that need to say "active"?

Comment: That has to be Active.  See [Gparted info](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgfl92lu1uzfhjp/2013-08-11_1013.png).